# matplotlib adding values to specific bars, but not the height

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

My DF looks like this:

```
ID    Ctg     Value_1   Result_1    Result_2     Result_3
1     Car     0.5       100         105          80
2     Bike    0.35      200         150          130 
3     Plane   0.51      45          70           77
4     Car     ...       ...         ...          ... 
5     Plane   ...       ...         ...          ... 
6     Plane   ...       ...         ...          ...  
7     Bike    ...       ...         ...          ... 
8     Car     ...       ...         ...          ... 
9     Car     ...       ...         ...          ...
```

```
distinct_Ctg = data.Ctg.unique()

for loop_count, i in enumerate(distinct_Ctg):
    
    # Subset for each category
    data_graph_sub = data.loc[data['Ctg'] == i]
    
    X = np.arange(len(data_graph_sub ))
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    ax.set_facecolor('#E6E6E6')
    bar_1 = ax.bar(X - 0.25, data_graph_sub['Result_1'], color = 'steelblue', width = 0.25) 
    bar_2 = ax.bar(X, data_graph_sub['Result_2'], color = 'orange', width = 0.25)
    bar_3 = ax.bar(X + 0.25, data_graph_sub['Result_3'], color = 'indianred', width = 0.25)
    
    plt.ylabel('Unit')
    plt.title(i +': This is my title')
    plt.grid(color='w', linestyle='solid')
    for spine in ax.spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)    
    ax.set_xticks(X) 
    ax.set_xticklabels(data_graph_sub.ID, rotation = 40, fontsize = 'small', ha = 'right')
    ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
    ax.yaxis.tick_left()
    
   
    blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='steelblue', label='Result from Programm 1')
    green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='Result from Programm 2')
    red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='indianred', label='Result from Programm 3')
    plt.legend(handles = [blue_patch, green_patch, red_patch])
    
    # plt.show()
    
    plt.savefig(r'graphs/' + str(loop_count) + '.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

With this I create one figure for each type in Ctg and the results look good to me so far.

I'd now like to add Value_1 from my DF to one of the three bars (to the steelblue bar coming from data_graph_sub['Result_1']) like here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html, but in this example the value is the height of the bar and it's plotted to all bars.

How can i realize this?

EDIT:
I added this, but it's not correct yet...

```
for z in bar_1:
    plt.text(z.get_x(), z.get_height(), data_graph_sub['Value_1'], size = 10)
```

How can I link the specific bar to the correct value in data_graph_sub['Value_1']?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With zip you can loop simultaneously through the bars and values:

```py
for bar, val in zip(bar_1, data_graph_sub['Value_1']):
    ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2, bar.get_height(), f'{val:0.2f}\n', 
            size=10, ha='center', va='center')
```